# Error due to Stringfrom method

Tags: c#

FRIENDS THE FOLLOWING PROGRAM GIVE ME ERROR WHILE I COMPILE IT.the bugs is in the **StringfromMonths**.showing that it is not exist in the current context.
   how it is not exist in the curren contest as i want to get a constant a string from the **enume Months** and at the same time convert it to string.

shall thankfull for respons!

```
using System;

enum Months

{

   September,
   Octobar,
   November = 11,
   December,

}

 class Montest

 {

 public static void Main()

 {

   string s;

    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a month");
    Console.WriteLine("September");
    Console.WriteLine("Octobar");
    Console.WriteLine("November");
    Console.WriteLine("December");
    s = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (s)
    {
        case "September":
            Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the Valuve {0}",StringfromMonths(Months.September));
            break;
        case "October":
            Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the Valuve {0}", StringfromMonths(Months.September));
            break;
        case "November":
            Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the Valuve {0}", StringfromMonths(Months.September));
            break;
        case "December":
            Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the Valuve {0}", StringfromMonths(Months.September));
            break;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: Funny, `the bug is in StringFromMonths  it doesn't exist in the current context`. And yes, I agree with the compiler, I can't see it. Lost in copy/paste?

Comment: Where is the StringfromMonths method?

Comment: LOVE when people try to reinvent the wheel.... What's wrong with built-in functions in .NET?

Comment: Long live copy&paste!

Comment: nono,i did mistake here i am trying to get string from enumeration Months

Comment: -1 for terrible formatting and the use of ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a method called `StringfromMonths` in your code and this, apart from the compiler error, seems really misleading because I suppose that this lost method returns a string, instead you are trying to print the numeric value of the enum `Months.September`...

If you really want to print the numeric value of a enum value, you need to convert to an integer.
So it is simply:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the value {0}", 
                   Convert.ToInt32(Months.September));
```

By the way, as written above, the Month of September has value = 0, October = 1, November=11, December = 12. (And all of your switch cases prints September?)

Last but not least, what is "Octobar"? A bar where you order 1 and get 8? I will go there every Saturday night. :-))))

Comment: haha Steve funny, thanks Alote.i did enough mistakes but still good people are here who resolved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Create the missing function:

```
static public string StringfromMonths(Months months)
{
    return months.ToString();
}
```

But my suggestion is: just do not use the function and show your values like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have selected September which has the Valuve {0}", Months.September);
```

Comment: Martin i want the value here but it return the name.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean with "value" and "name"? Do you mean the numeric value? Like "November" is converted into 11?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you have no StringfromMonths method. One thing you could do instead of that is this:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(Months), Months.September):
```